# Cannot install cURL and PHP's cURL library on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, curl, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install curl and php5-curl on a Ubuntu 14.04 server, but I'm getting the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3 php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libcurl3 is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapparmor-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1) but 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
                    Depends: perlapi-5.18.2
 libcgi-fast-perl : Depends: libfcgi-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libdbd-mysql-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1
 libdbi-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1
 liblocale-gettext-perl : PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.18.1-4) but 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
                          PreDepends: perlapi-5.18.1
 libperl5.18 : Depends: perl-base (= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1) but 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
 libsub-name-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1
 libterm-readkey-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1
 libtext-charwidth-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.18.1-4) but 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
                          Depends: perlapi-5.18.1
 libtext-iconv-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.18.1-4) but 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
                      Depends: perlapi-5.18.1
 libtext-soundex-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1
 perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1) but 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Did you run `apt-get -f install;`? What was the result of that?

Comment: Can you only try with `sudo apt-get install curl php5-curl`?

Comment: I could be totally wrong, but I dont think libcurl3 is necessary unless you plan on writing some C/Cpp code with Curl. Just a fyi. I never needed to install libCurl on any VM I setup using PHP as far as I aware of.

Comment: ChrisForrence I get the same error when I run apt-get -f install.

Comment: id did dpkg -i perl-base_5.18.2-2_i386.deb and got
(Reading database ... 123753 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack perl-base_5.18.2-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking perl-base (5.18.2-2) over (5.14.2-6ubuntu2.5) ...
Setting up perl-base (5.18.2-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...

Comment: ran apt-get install -f php5-curl
libapparmor-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1) but 5.18.2-2 is to be installed
 libapt-pkg-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
 libauthen-pam-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
 libcgi-fast-perl : Depends: libfcgi-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libio-pty-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
 libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
 libperl5.18 : Depends: perl-base (= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1) but 5.18.2-2 is to be installed
 perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1) but 5.18.2-2 is to be installed

Answer (score 0):

Ran **apt-get -f install** by itself and it fixed the problems. I miss understood the **-f install** and thought I needed to run it with the package with it. It wound up updating everything and even installed other packages I was trying to install.

Thanks for the help.